# How do I find references to zstd in the ubuntu mailing lists using google.com/search?

Tags: google-search, mailing-list

[Sep'17 ubuntu-devel-discuss mailing archive page](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-September/thread.html)

has the line:

```
FW: zstd package on Ubuntu LTS 16.04   Yann Collet
```

I am attempting to locate any additional references to zstd in the ubuntu mailing lists. I used:

[https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Alists.ubuntu.com+zstd](https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Alists.ubuntu.com%20xenial)

which produces no matches, not even the one listed above.

[https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Alists.ubuntu.com+xenial](https://www.google.com/search?&q=site%3Alists.ubuntu.com%20xenial)

on the other hand produces a number of matches from the ubuntu-devel-discuss list.

How do I find references to zstd in the ubuntu mailing lists using google.com/search?